# Swift Modal View Controller with transparent background

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller, swift2

I know this topic is quite popular, but I'm a little iniciate problem in a programming language, the fact is that I still do not understand where I put the code. Well, I'll tell the whole case:

[image]

I'm trying to make a modal Swift in a little different from normal: By clicking on a button, the ViewController is displayed (following modal type) on the screen, but with transparent background. Only the blue View with label will be displayed. When this ViewController is presented, it is with transparent background, but as soon as it completes the transition, it will stay with the black background. Already deactivated the opaque option, and tested some options, but nothing this troubleshooting.

Some can help me?

The video is a test in the simulator on the case (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wT8Uwmq9yqY).

I'm starting with swift, and I'm still pretty lost with how to program in Xcode, I read an answer to a question that has the following code to solve this:

```
self.presentingViewController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
self.presentingViewController.definesPresentationContext = YES;
modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
```

Where do I put this code?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27669699/transparent-background-for-modally-presented-viewcontroller

Comment: I must keep the segue between the button and the ViewController (modal)?
because without follows presents nothing, with the following features black background yet.

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598099/present-uiviewcontroller-as-a-modal-with-transparent-background?rq=1

Answer (score 273, accepted):

You can do it like this:

**In your main view controller:**

```
func showModal() {
    let modalViewController = ModalViewController()
    modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    presentViewController(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**In your modal view controller:**

```
class ModalViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        view.opaque = false
    }
}
```

**If you are working with a storyboard:**

Just add a Storyboard Segue with `Kind` set to `Present Modally` to your modal view controller and on this view controller set the following values:

- Background = Clear Color
- Drawing = Uncheck the Opaque checkbox
- Presentation = Over Current Context

As [Crashalot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/144088/crashalot) pointed out in his comment: Make sure the **segue** only uses `Default` for both `Presentation` and `Transition`. Using `Current Context` for `Presentation` makes the modal turn black instead of remaining transparent.

Comment: Are you working with storyboards? Please see my edited answer. I just tried it and it works

Comment: After you edit, follow his instructions and it worked properly. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :-)

Comment: Make sure the segue only uses `Default` for both `Presentation` and `Transition`. Using `Current Context` for `Presentation` makes the modal turn black instead of remaining transparent.

Comment: @Crashalot Thanks for your comment! I added your info to the question to make it more visible.

Comment: Swift3 - slideMenuController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
            present(slideMenuController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: @Crashalot that was very crucial in my case . thanks

Comment: How can I make this work for navigationController ` let vc = NewRquestViewController()
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        let nvc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        self.present(nvc, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: works like a charm!

Comment: Just to be really really precise as this is a fiddly one. In the storyboard its the *View controller* that needs to have Presentation set to 'Over Current Context', The *view* background colour as transparent (and untick opaque)

Comment: Can you make it show over a tabbar? I tried the method above and it displays over the previous VC, but under tabbar.

Comment: Setting viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen solved it!