# iOS 11 navigation bar transparent with large titles

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have default preferences for uinavigationbar:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .red
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.99997437, blue: 0.9999912977, alpha: 1)]
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.99997437, blue: 0.9999912977, alpha: 1)]
        }
        UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.99997437, blue: 0.9999912977, alpha: 1)
```

Structure: **UINaviagtionController -> PostsTableViewController -> PostTableViewController**.

I want to have large navigation bar on PostsViewController (with opaque background color) and transparent navigation bar on PostViewController.

In PostTableViewController i add:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .clear

        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            print("asd")
            self.tableView.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea = false
            self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        } else {
            self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        }
```

Navigation bar is BLACK. I dont understand how make it transparent...
[image: PostsTableViewController]
[image: PostTableViewController]

**UPDATE:**

git hub repository: https://github.com/Mazorati/testnavbar

i set isTranslucent = true, but large navigation becomes also transparent. Only default navigation is ok.

[image: PostsViewController]

[image: PostsViewController]

[image: PostViewController]

But i want navigationbar color to be opaque, so:

```
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .red
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
```

As the result:

[image: opaque large navigation]

3D layers:

[image: 3d layers]

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33106533/1214800

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question. I use push segue

Comment: Doesn't matter. Same view stack, different transition. Did you try it?

Comment: @Mazorati Have you been able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried changing it to translucent?

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

UPDATE:

You must remember that the navigation bar belongs to the UINavigationController which holds the views inside it, so that when you change it in one it changes for all.

The solution would be to change it to translucent in the second view controller's viewWillAppear method and change it to not translucent in the viewDidDissapear method. Play with the viewWill and viewDid appear methods until you find the right one for your needs.

Comment: thanks. Check my update to this post. PostsViewController large navigation is without background now... How to add background to this?

Comment: I updated my response, please check it works your what you want

Answer (score -1):

Try this, this make your navigation bar transparent.

```
    let img = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = img
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(img, for: .default)
```