# Instance Member Cannot Be Used on Type when pushing UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift4, programmatically-created

I am programmatically setting up ViewControllers (no storyboard).

I want to pass data to the next VC, and while I know how to do that with a segue and a storyboard, I can't figure out how to do it purely programmatically.

I get the error "Instance Member Cannot Be Used on Type..."

```
// Create Next View Controller Variable

let nextViewController = CarbonCalculatorResultsViewController()

// Pass data to next view controller.  There is already a variable in that file: var userInformation: UserInformation?

CarbonCalculatorResultsViewController.userInformation = userInformation

// Push next View Controller
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
```

Do I need to instantiate the next VC before I can pass data?  That's what [this answer seems to talk about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748069/swift-4-load-next-viewcontroller) yet I don't have a Storyboard.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1: Setup your destination class**

In `CarbonCalculatorResultsViewController` class, declare a `var` to receive data like so:

```
class CarbonCalculatorResultsViewController: UIViewController {
    var foo: String? {
        didSet {
            // What you'd like to do with the data received
            print(foo ?? "")
        }
    }

    ovevride func viewDidLoad() {
       //
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Prepare data in your source class**

```
let nextViewController = CarbonCalculatorResultsViewController()
// You have access of the variable in CarbonCalculatorResultsViewController
nextViewController.foo = <data_you_want_to_pass>

// Push next View Controller
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
```

Then, every time the `CarbonCalculatorResultsViewController` comes alive, the `didSet{}` of `foo` would be called.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the variable on the `Object`, not on the `Class`

Replace: `CarbonCalculatorResultsViewController.userInformation = userInformation`

With:
`nextViewController.userInformation = userInformation`

**Note:**

`CarbonCalculatorResultsViewController` is the `Class`.

`nextViewController` is the `Object`.

Your full code should look like this:

```swift
// Create Next View Controller Variable

let nextViewController = CarbonCalculatorResultsViewController()

// Pass data to next view controller.  There is already a variable in that file: var userInformation: UserInformation?

nextViewController.userInformation = userInformation

// Push next View Controller
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

The current sample code (above) is setting a value to a static variable (owned by the `CarbonCalculatorResultsViewController.Type`.

What I believe you want to implement is the following instead:

```swift
// Create Next View Controller Variable

let nextViewController = CarbonCalculatorResultsViewController()

// Pass data to next view controller.  There is already a variable in that file: var userInformation: UserInformation?

nextViewController.userInformation = userInformation

// Push next View Controller
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
```

This sample code is setting a value to the instance variable `userInformation` on the type `nextViewController`.