# how to make the modal view with a transparent background in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, xcode11

Anyone knows how to to make the modal view with a transparent background.

Exactly like the below link in swift

[Swift Modal View Controller with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104743/swift-modal-view-controller-with-transparent-background)

Comment: I stand corrected from my previous comment, so I deleted it (and will upvote your question). Right now it appears you *can* give a background to the modal view by using a `Rectangle` inside a `ZStack`. BUT... the default for a modal view seems to be based on the light/dark mode setting. If you make that Rectangle fill be `Color.clear, you'll still have a background that covers the underlying view....

Comment: Hopefully a future version of SwiftUI will have your feature, but I'm think your best bet is to not use a modal but instead create a full screen view with a transparent background and anti it onto the screen and provide a way to dismiss it. Since a transparent modal won't show it's edges, you'll essentially *fake* a modal.

Comment: mmh could be a solution something like that (is just a View that appears inside a ZStack) https://github.com/peppesapienza/random-code/blob/master/transparent-modal-swiftUI.swift ?

Answer (score 13):

I am using coordinator pattern,  creating view in assembly

```
let view = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftuiview)
view.view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

inside router just present this UIHostingController

```
module.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
navigationController.present(module, animated: animated, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that the UIHostingController's backgroundColor does not contain a .clear

Comment: Found a way to make the view atleast clear by setting view.view.background to nil instead of .clear, then all you do is set the opacity to zero ether on the hosting controller level or on the SwftUI View itself

Answer (score 5):

If you wanting to blur the background of a SwiftUI from UIKit Project and are possibly using SwiftUI View for a Modal View then I had the same problem recently and created a UIViewController that takes the UIHostController (UIViewController basically), then alters the HostingController View's alpha, puts a blur at the back and presents it to the parent view.

I Have created a gist with the file in it for public use
https://gist.github.com/Ash-Bash/93fd55d89c1e36f592d3868f6b29b259

Heres the working example:

```
// Initialises BlurredHostingController
var blurredHostingController = BlurredHostingController()

// Sets the Hosting View for the SwiftUI View Logic
blurredHostingController.hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())

// Blur Tweaks for blurredHostingController
blurredHostingController.blurEffect = .systemMaterial
blurredHostingController.translucentEffect = .ultrathin

// Presents View Controller as a Modal View Controller
self.present(blurredHostingController animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here's the result from macCatalyst
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Present:

```
let rootView = Text("Hello world")
let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: rootView)
controller.view.backgroundColor = .clear
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(controller, animated: true)
```

Dismiss:

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't get the ideal way to do so, but I got a workaround for this.

So, In order to present a view modally, you can take a ZStack and group multiple views in it and handle it with a @State variable like this.

Here I have given the background colour to the view for better explanation.

```
struct ContentView : View {
   @State private var showModally = false
   var body : some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.red
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation{
                    self.showModally = true
                }
            }) {
                Text("Push Modally")
            }
        }
        
        ModalView(show: $showModally)
            .offset(y: self.showModally ? 0 : UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            .animation(.spring())
        
    }
  }
}

struct ModalView: View {
  @Binding var show : Bool
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        
        VStack {
            Color.white
        }
        .frame(height : 400)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
    .background(Color.clear)
    .onTapGesture {
        self.show = false
    }
  }
}
```

In this, the Modal View will be presented modally over the content view and will be dismissed by a tap.

Comment: How can this be modified so that it covers a UITabBar?

Comment: include the TabView inside a ZStack and rest keep the content as it is. 
 something like this :- ZStack { TabView { Content } ModalView }

Answer (score 2):

**iOS 16.4+**

You can use the new modifier to display a fullscreen modal with a transparent background:

[presentationBackground(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/presentationbackground(_:))

*Sets the presentation background of the enclosing sheet using a shape
style.*

Here's an example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSettings = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("View Settings") {
            showSettings = true
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showSettings) {
            SettingsView()
                .presentationBackground(.thickMaterial) // <-- this 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this on parent view, assign modalPresentationStyle as a .formSheet and set size as parent view by assigning preferredContentSize to hostingVC.

```
  if segue.identifier == "AnotherView", let hostingController = segue.destination as? HostingSwiftUIView {
    hostingController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    hostingController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 700, height: 300) // customise as per View
    hostingController.rootView = AnyView(AnotherView())
}
```

Here is Child view as present view modally.

```
struct AnotherView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Second View")
            .bold()
            .font(.largeTitle)
    }
}
```

It will look like:
[image]